# What is the meaning for reduceByKey(_ ++ _)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Recently I had scenario to store the the data in keyValue Pair and came across a function `reduceByKey(_ ++ _)` . This is more of shorthand syntax. I am not able to understand what this actually means.

Ex: `reduceBykey(_ + _)`  means `reduceByKey((a,b)=>(a+b))`

So `reduceByKey(_ ++ _)` means ??

I am able to create Key value pair out of data using `reduceByKey(_ ++ _)`.

```
val y = sc.textFile("file:///root/My_Spark_learning/reduced.txt")

y.map(value=>value.split(","))
  .map(value=>(value(0),value(1),value(2)))
  .collect
  .foreach(println)

(1,2,3)
(1,3,4)
(4,5,6)
(7,8,9)

y.map(value=>value.split(","))
  .map(value=>(value(0),Seq(value(1),value(2))))
  .reduceByKey(_ ++ _)
  .collect
  .foreach(println)

(1,List(2, 3, 3, 4))
(4,List(5, 6))
(7,List(8, 9))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`reduceByKey(_ ++ _)` translates to `reduceByKey((a,b) => a ++ b)`.

`++` is a [method](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/index.html#scala.collection.TraversableLike@++:[B%3E:A,That](that:Traversable[B])(implicitbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Repr,B,That]):That) defined on `List` that concatenates another list to it.

So, for key 1 in the sample data, `a` will be `List(2,3)` and `b` will be `List(3,4)` and hence the concatenation of `List(2,3)` and `List(3,4)` (`List(2,3) ++ List(3,4)`) would yield `List(2,3,3,4)`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation .

Answer (score 1):

`reduceByKey(_ ++ _)` is equivalent to  `reduceByKey((x,y)=> x ++ y)`
`reduceByKey` takes two parameters, apply a function and returns

At the first it crates a set and  `++` just adds collections together, combining elements of both sets.

For each key It keeps appending in the list. In your case of 1 as a key x will be `List(2,3)` and y will `List (3,4)` and `++` will add both as `List (2,3,3,4)`

If you had another value like `(1,4,5)` then the x would be `List(4,5)` in this case and y should be `List (2,3,3,4)` and result would be `List(2,3,3,4,4,5)`